# Vuetify - strict datatable custom filter

Tags: vue.js, filter, datatable, vuetify.js, strict

So I have a data table whereby the names of the objects are similar and case sensitive like "A", "Aa", or "a" and I'm having issues trying to filter the data by those exact values. I'm filtering my data using a v-select bound to the search property of the data table. When creating the custom filter, the only two options I've found are by filtering the specific column by the search input:

```
customFilter(items, search, filter) {
    search = search.toString().toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(row => filter(row["name"], search));
}
```

or filtering the Object.keys:

```
customFilter(items, search, filter) {
    search = search.toString().toLowerCase();
    return items.filter(i => (
        Object.keys(i).some(j => filter(i[j], search))
    ))
}
```

With how the custom filter works, I can't seem to use the search parameter without it being put to lower case as removing .toLowerCase() breaks it completely and using a different method on the Objects.key like .find() rather than .some() results still filters the "Aa" items when selecting "A" or "a".

Is there any way I can use the custom filter in order to filter my items both case sensitive and by the string exactly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using the search and custom filter of the data table was the wrong way about it as they're too restricted. I just linked the datatable to a separate array which I filter myself when selecting an option in the v-select.